# how to unifying date format in php?

Tags: php, date

I have multiple date format in my database like this :

```
13 October
02/11/2017
23/07/2014 at 15:12
Sunday 18 December - 09:15
11 September 2017 at 09h01 
18d
October 8, 2017 - 1:55pm
```

How can I make them under the same format (using php ) so it can be easy to sort my rows by date ?

I tried with `strtotime()` by it was not so helpful .

Comment: Many of those are ambiguous, so you simply can't reconstruct the actual point in time from that.

Comment: This is not possible. "13 October" and "18d" don't include enough data to generate an accurate date from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many situations here that could not be formated into a unified date:

- 13 October: will convert to that day of month for the CURRENT year
- 18d: i myself could not guess
- you cannot have "-" or "at" in the date between the date and time
- a time like 09h01 will convert if you change the "h" for a ":"

The only way i see here is to do this in 2 stages.

1) start saving the dates in a unified format :)

2) create a parser that will cover all scenarios and check all dates are correct.

Comment: 18d mean 18 day ago and the problem that the database contains up to 2k rows so i think i have to make my own parser

Answer (score -1):

Use [`strptime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) and use the right format:

```
array strptime ( string $date, string $format )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer m i tried that `strptime ( '23/07/2014 at 15:12' , %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S)` but it didn't work